# WinRT assigning a token to asynchronous task

Tags: asynchronous, windows-runtime

I wonder about the reason of assigning a token to an asynchronous task, as in the following example:

```
  var ctSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doSomething(), ctSource.Token);
```

The MSDN documentation insists on passing a token to the running method in addition to assigning it to task, but to me it appears as an unnatural duplication.

1. If a token is assigned to a task, does it mean, that `ctSource.Cancel()`automatically triggers `TaskCancelledException` for the task?
2. Is there a way to retrieve the assigned token from the task (other than by sending it as an argument) ?

If neither of those, what is the reason of assigning a token to a task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. If a token is assigned to a task, does it mean, that ctSource.Cancel()automatically triggers TaskCancelledException for the task?

The task could start anytime, now or later. So if it happens that the token has a cancellation request before that task has started, the scheduler itself will throw the `OperationCanceledException`, and your action `() => doSomething()` is never invoked. So, the token is being passed to the factory, not the task. This is used by the `StartNew(...)` method.

> 2. Is there a way to retrieve the assigned token from the task (other than by sending it as an argument) ?

No. Tasks do not know about `CancellationToken`, only the implementation. Tasks do not auto-cancel themselves. The function running within a task is responsible for exiting when a cancellation is requested.

You are the owner of the `CancellationTokenSource`. So pass it to whomever needs it.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doSomething(ctSource.Token), ctSource.Token);
```

If you are not the owner of `doSomething()` (from 3rd party DLL), then you cannot cancel that operation, unless it accepts a `CancellationToken`.

Comment: Thank you Laith for such a comprehensive answer. Since there is no way to specify cancellation token with 'await', does it mean, that when cancellation is requested  while my task is awaiting another task, that other task will still run to completion, until I regain the control and stop thread with token.throwIfCancellationRequested?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. The running task will run to completion. Once it's completed, you can check `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`.